# Reducer gets called in unexpected way - Redux Saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, reducers

Hey there I am having a minor issue, trying to make small todo application. The error shows in the console of a browser, UI doesn't breaks but it drives me nuts because I want to know why is this happening?

Main component where I am calling setChecked with it's arguments, id of an item to be checked and checkedValue(true or false).

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import { setChecked } from "../redux/actions/todoActions";

export default function Main() {
  const tasks = useSelector((state) => state.todoReducer.tasks);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const taskItems = Array.from(tasks).map((item, index) => {
    return item.checked !== true && item.date ? (
      <div
        key={index}
        className="item-row"
        onClick={() => dispatch(setChecked(item.id, !item.checked))}
      >
        <label className="check-flag">
          <span className="check-flag-label">{item.title}</span>
          <FormControlLabel
            className="checkbox"
            control={
              <Checkbox className="checkbox-native" checked={item.checked} />
            }
          ></FormControlLabel>
        </label>
      </div>
    ) : (
      ""
    );
  });

  return (
    <main className="main">
      <div className="wrap">{taskItems}</div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

setChecked action

```
const setChecked = (id, checked) => ({
  type: TODO.SET_CHECKED,
  itemToChange: { id, checked },
});
```

todoSaga

```
function* handleGetTodo(action) {
  yield put({ type: TODO.GET_TODO });
}

function* handleSetChecked(action) {
  yield put({ type: TODO.SET_CHECKED, action });
}

export default function* watchTodo(action) {
  yield takeEvery(TODO.GET_TODO, handleGetTodo);

  yield takeLatest(TODO.SET_CHECKED, handleSetChecked);
}
```

reducer

```
const todoReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TODO.GET_TODO:
      return { ...state };
    case TODO.SET_CHECKED:
      var tasks = state.tasks;

      tasks = tasks.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === action.itemToChange.id) {
          return { ...item, checked: action.itemToChange.checked };
        }

        return { ...item };
      });

      return { ...state, tasks: tasks };

    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
};
```

[First call - this is ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNa7B.png)

[Second call - whole action gets passed to action so now i have action.action.itemToChange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2qHn.jpg)

I am using React.StrictMode and I understand it has to calls some functions twice which isn't a problem but why does he makes nested action object inside of action object itself? I hope that I am expressing myself successfully.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Re: the weird property name, that’s just how redux-saga works behind the scenes.  It is a middleware so it knows what to do with an action that looks like that.  Scroll down to the part “actionDispatched(action)” in the API docs https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/

Comment: *action : Object - The dispatched Redux action. If the action was dispatched by a Saga then the action will have a property SAGA_ACTION set to true (SAGA_ACTION can be imported from @redux-saga/symbols).*

Comment: Re: nested action, that’s because of the action you are creating in your handleSetChecked.  yield put({ type: TODO.SET_CHECKED, action }) — you are passing the whole action to a property action.

Answer (score 0):

Right now your saga serves no purpose because you are taking an action and then dispatching essentially the same action.  In fact you might be creating an infinite loop by doing this.

The reason that you get a nested action in the version of your action which is created by redux-saga is due to how you are creating the action in your `handleSetChecked` function.  It receives an argument `action` which is the entire action object that was intercepted by `take`.  It then uses `put` to dispatch a new action which looks like `yield put({ type: TODO.SET_CHECKED, action });`  That action has properties `type` and `action`, where `action` is the entire original action.